# SQL joins and aggregation functions

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create summary of order values grouped by dates and the city where the order occurred, so for example, if there were 10 orders made on the 21st of may 2020 in NYC, I would have the order date 5.21.2020, city : nyc and then the total value of those 21 orders. I would then have exactly the same for another city on the same date. Now I would need to add a new row that has the total value of all the orders that occurred on the 21st of may ( so NYC + city etc.). How is this possible ? My query is like this :

```
FROM orderline AS R JOIN warehouse AS V ON R.product = V.product
JOIN orders AS O ON R.ordernb=O.ordernb
JOIN SALESMAN AS S ON T.id=S.id
GROUP BY O.date,S.city
ORDER BY O.date

It should look like this :

Date             City           Value
5.21.2020        Nyc            $5000
5.21.2020        Dallas         $10000
5.21.2020                       $15000
----------
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is your DBMS? You may be looking for `GROUPING SETS`, provided your DBMS supports these. Otherwise you can just write two queries, one grouped by city and date, the other just by date and then use `UNION ALL` to combine the two result sets.

Comment: Grouping sets did the trick in this case